# Are minimizing a function and root finding the same?

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, self-learning, roots, maxima-minima

What is the relationship between minimizing a function and finding a root of an equation? Are the the same? I know in both problem we have similar algorithms, such as gradient decent, or newton's methods.

For example, Let use assume $x$ is a scalar. Finding a root for an equation $f(x)=b$ is checking where the function $f(x)-b$ cross the x axis. This is definitely not equal to minimize $f(x)-b$.

But in the [convex optimization book](http://stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/), Minimizing $\|Ax-b\|_2^2$ is equal to the solution of the linear system $Ax=b$.

What I am missing? in which case we can transfer optimization to root finding?

Comment: only for the case that $b\in\mathrm{img}(A)$, otherwise it's not the same.

Comment: @hxd1011 Maximising/Minimising involve derivatives

Comment: @Navaro, thanks. I understand you can use root finding to perform optimization to get an analytical solution. But my question was trying to ask can you transform one root finding problem into a optimization problem?

Comment: @max Thanks Max, could you educate what is img of A? or give me some examples?

Comment: In principle the problem of finding roots of $f(x)-b$ is the same as minimizing the objective function $||f(x)-b||^2$. This is because the function $||f(x)-b||^2$ is zero if $f(x)=b$, and greater than zero otherwise. However, in practice the optimization problem may be numerically more difficult to solve than the original root finding problem.

Comment: @NickAlger this is the answer I wanted. Thanks. One question, according to your statement, we can use all kinds of norms, right? not necessary to be L2

Comment: Yes, other norms can be used. For example, in the field of compressed sensing it is popular to use the L1 norm. Also, I should revise my previous comment to say "if there *exists* a root, then the methods are equivalent", since the optimization problem will have a solution even if there are no roots of the function. This is what Max is getting at with his comment above.

Comment: @NickAlger so can i say every root finding problem can be converted into an optimization problem, but the reverse is not true

Comment: You could say that, I suppose. By the way, you can (sort of) go in the reverse direction. Since the gradient is zero at a minima, one can search for solutions to the optimization problem by performing root finding on the gradient function. Note that zeros of the gradient could also be maxima or saddlepoints, so some care must be taken when doing this.

Comment: @hxd1011 the problems coincide when teh *residuals* are zero: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares#Problem_statement to give an example, where it's not the same: let $v\in\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\left\{0\right\}$ be any vector and $w\in\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\left\{0,v\right\}$ another vector. Now consider $\mathbb{R}\ni x\mapsto f(x):=x\cdot v$. Clearly there is no solution to the system $f\left(x\right)=w$, but of course there is a solution to $\min \left\|f(x)-w\right\|$: the $x_0$ such that $f(x_0)$ is the orthogonal projection of $w$ onto the substace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ spanned by $v$.

Answer (score 10):

Root-finding and optimization are not the same, but a root-finding problem can be reformulated into an optimization problem. That is, we can construct an optimization problem from a root-finding problem where the solution to both problems are the same.

The value(s) of $x$ that satisfy $f(x) = b \implies f(x)-b = 0$ will also be the global minimizer(s) of the optimizition problem min $||f(x)-b||^2_2$.

The idea is that the $x^*$ that makes $f(x^*) = b$ also makes $f(x^*)-b = 0$ and will also be the global minimizer for $||f(x^*)-b||^2_2$ since the lowest value it can acheive is $0$.

*If the function $f$ and its domain have the right mathematical properties than you can convert it to a optimization problem. Things like differentiability of $f$.

Answer (score 1):

Footnote to @Roby's answer: As a practical note, if you're using an off-the-shelf optimizer to solve $f(x)=b$ by minimizing $||f(x)-b||^2_2$, you have to be careful that a minimum you find is actually a solution. As an example, suppose you're trying to solve $f(x)=b$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$, where

$
\begin{split}
f(x) &= x^2 + 2\\
b &= 1
\end{split}$

Then $x = 0$ minimizes $||f(x)-b||^2_2$, but it doesn't solve $f(x)=b$, since no real $x$ solves $x^2 + 2 = 1$.

So, to the question, you can use an optimization method to find roots, by minimizing $||f(x)-b||^2_2$, and checking that the objective-function value is $0$ at the minimum. That said, not all minima, even global minima, correspond to roots, since not all equations have roots.

Comment: This doesn't differ in any way from the other answers given years ago.  When you choose to answer old posts, we expect answers that are unique, or go beyond previously answered questions.

Comment: I'm just trying to point out a gotcha to watch out for if you do use an optimization method to find roots.

Comment: I understand, and have not downvoted or taken action.  Thanks for the explanation, @Adam !

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I edited the answer to make it clear that this was meant as a footnote.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not same. In your case, assuming that columns of $A$ span vector $b$ and $||Ax-b||$ being norm which is non-negative, the problem of investigating minima is similar to finding solution of $Ax-b=0$.

Comment: Optimization is one tool for solving equations and finding zeros of functions. It provides a few efficient algorithms to for this task that are the main techniques of Machine Learning and Artificial Neural networks.